# Телеграм бот для тех. поддержки

Tags: python, telebot

Задача:

1. Пользователи пишут в бота свои вопросы,
2. Бот пересылает их сообщения в Чат Поддержки,
3. В этом чате помощники отвечают на сообщение (через reply),
4. Бот пересылает ответ обратно пользователю.

Не получается выполнить 4 пункт, так как в сообщении нет параметра chat_id того пользователя который задал вопрос.
Как еще это можно сделать?

```
# Функция, обрабатывающая команду /help
@bot.message_handler(commands=["help"])
def help(m, res=False):
   markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
   button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Отмена', callback_data='cancel')
   markup.add(button1)
   msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Задайте вопрос боту.', reply_markup=markup)
   bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, helpBot)
   
# Функция, отправляющая вопрос от пользователя в чат поддержки
def helpBot(m):
   bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, m.chat.id, m.message_id)

# Получение сообщений от юзера,
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(m):
   # здесь если чат id равен id чата поддержки, то отправить сообщение пользователю который задал вопрос
   if int(m.chat.id) == int(TO_CHAT_ID):
       bot.send_message(????, m.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете просто добавить переменную ( `help_user_id = m.from_user.id` ) запоминающую айди юзера, который вызвал команду /help.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["help"])
def help(m, res=False):
   global help_user_id
   help_user_id = m.from_user.id
   markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
   button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Отмена', callback_data='cancel')
   markup.add(button1)
   msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Задайте вопрос боту.', reply_markup=markup)
   bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, helpBot)

# Функция, отправляющая вопрос от пользователя в чат поддержки
def helpBot(m):
     bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, m.chat.id, m.message_id)

# Получение сообщений от юзера,
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(m):
   # здесь если чат id равен id чата поддержки, то отправить сообщение пользователю который задал вопрос
   if int(m.chat.id) == int(TO_CHAT_ID):
      bot.send_message(help_user_id, m.text)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отлично. Спасибо)

Comment: но если нажать кнопку отмены, функция все еще ждёт ввода для отправки. как тогда прерывать register_next_step_handler?

Comment: @Валерий bot.clear_step_handler_by_chat_id(chat_id=call.message.chat.id)