# Как сделать обратную связь в тг боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot

нужна помощь. Я хочу сделать "Бота Техподдержку". Я сделал так, чтобы бот получал сообщение от пользователя, и после бот пересылал его в чат. Но я не смог найти в инете нормальную инфу, как сделать так, чтобы при ответе на сообщение в группе, бот от своего имени писал это пользователю. Заранее спасибо
Вот код:

```
import config
import telebot

TO_CHAT_ID = -868598805

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Здравствуйте!, {0.first_name}!\nЯ, бот созданный чтобы помочь улучшить качество продукции. Если у Вас имеется отзыв о продукции компании 'INSOLITTA', то напишите его ниже".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode='html')
    
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def all_messages(message):
    bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def negry(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

P.s Я обнаружил такой баг, в случае ответа на сообщение в группе, бот дублирует сообщение. Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Посмотрите [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1379811/%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в программировании, можете пожалуйста подсказать, как воспользоваться тем кодом. У меня есть дополнительный фай конфига, в котором я храню токен бота, основной код выше. Как мне воспользоваться тем кодом?

Answer (score 0):

Вот код, который будет сохранять запросы после чего давать ответить на них:

```py
from telebot import types

import config
import telebot

TO_CHAT_ID = -905776749

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

requests_queue = []


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     "Здравствуйте!, {0.first_name}!\nЯ, бот созданный чтобы помочь улучшить качество продукции. Если "
                     "у Вас имеется отзыв о продукции компании 'INSOLITTA', то напишите его ниже".format(
                         message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
                     parse_mode='html')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, help_bot)


# Функция, отправляющая вопрос от пользователя в чат поддержки
def help_bot(message):
    requests_queue.append((message.message_id, message.chat.id))
    bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup([[
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Ответить', callback_data=f'answer{message.chat.id}')
    ]])
    bot.send_message(TO_CHAT_ID, f"Действие:", reply_markup=markup_inline)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, help_bot)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["requests"], func=lambda m: int(m.chat.id) == int(TO_CHAT_ID))
def all_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Доступные запросы:")
    for i, req in enumerate(requests_queue):
        bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, req[1], req[0])
        markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup([[
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Ответить', callback_data=f'answer{req[1]}')
        ]])
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Действие:", reply_markup=markup_inline)


def send_answer(message: types.Message, call, chat_id):
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Ответ отправлен!")
    bot.send_message(chat_id, message.text)
    for i, req in enumerate(requests_queue):
        if int(req[1]) == int(chat_id):
            del requests_queue[i]


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer_callback(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    if call.data.startswith("answer"):
        chat_id = int(call.data[6:])

        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Отправьте ответ на запрос")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, lambda msg: send_answer(msg, call, chat_id))


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Я очень благодарен тебе, но имеется возможность сделать так, чтобы вместо личного чата, была группа?

Comment: @KEPCHUK Ошибочка всё работает (я просто забыл выдать права боту)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Извините, все работает. Но есть вопрос, можно ли сделать так, чтобы запросы автоматически появлялись в группе, без команды?

Comment: @KEPCHUK исправил ответ